# How to Join in LINQ using Lambda expressions and get the result in DTO?

Tags: linq, join, lambda

var query=from e in DataContext.Employees
              join d in DataContext.Dept
              on e.DeptId  equals d.Id
              join o in DataContext.OtherInfo
              on e.Id equals o.EmployeeId 
              where e.EmployeeId==4 
              select new Employee_Dept//DTO
              {
                  EmployeeName=e.Name,
                  DeptName=d.Name
                  EmployeeId=e.ID
                  DeptId=d.Id
                  ContactNo=o.ContactNo
              }

I want to write it using Lambda expressions this is could write -

```
var query = DataContext.Employees.Join(Dept,e=>e.DeptId,d=>d.Id,(e,d)).Where(e=>e.EmployeeId=4)
```

can anyone help me complete this query. Thanks for your help.

Comment: why? join extension methods are ugly--use the query syntax you already have.

Comment: My Boss's wish is my command unfortunately....ya but i feel that too..

Comment: Agree with David. Extension syntax might look "cooler" to person coding it, but it will get changed to query syntax by the next developer that sees it because it's a pain to comprehend.

Comment: please don't take this as "go challenge your boss", but does he or she have a valid reason for this? the only real winner here is query syntax because it's easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's usually wrong to use `join` in LINQ to SQL](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/). Just write:

```
var query=from e in DataContext.Employees
          where e.EmployeeId==4 
          select new Employee_Dept//DTO
          {
              EmployeeName=e.Name,
              DeptName=d.Dept.Name
              EmployeeId=e.ID
              DeptId=d.Dept.Id
          }
```

Comment: I would agree that using join decreases readability, but your rewrite makes an assumption that isn't evident in the original question: that there exists an association between an employee and their department (i.e. the Dept property on Employee you reference)

Comment: @Rich, as that's the default behavior of L2S, I don't think that's such a big assumption.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Craig Stuntz that it is wrong usage of Join, but you can express the same LINQ query using extension methods in following way:

```
return DataContext.Employees
         .Join(DataContext.Dept, e => e.DeptId, d => d.Id, (e,d) => new { Employee = e, Department = d })
         .Join(DataContext.OtherInfo, s => s.Employee.Id, o => o.EmployeeId, (s, o) => new { Employee => s.Employee, Department = s.Department, OtherInfo = o })
         .Where(e => e.Employee.Id == 4)
         .Select(e => select new Employee_Dept//DTO
          {
              EmployeeName=e.Employee.Name,
              DeptName=e.Department.Name
              EmployeeId=e.Employee.ID
              DeptId=e.Department.Id
              ContactNo=e.OtherInfo.ContactNo
          }
```